# Could not get dependencies for project reference when mixing .NET Core and .NET Framework projects

Tags: .net, .net-core

I recently pulled down a project that had upgraded to .NET Core 3.1.  The rest of my projects are running .NET Framework 4.5.1, and use references from that .NET Core project.  When I try to add these references, I get the error "Could not get dependencies for project reference".  In Visual Studio, IntelliSense still completes code in the .NET Framework for the .NET Core code, but I still get the error.

Is there any way to import and reference this package?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff Rule of thumb is that .NET Framework projects cannot consume .NET Core libraries.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi. That was the answer I both suspected, and didn't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Lex Li's answer from above.  They did turn out to be incompatible, prompting me to replace the old projects with .NET core projects.  It was a hassle but worth it by far.  Using entity framework make life much easier, too.